# Rewrite$\int {\frac{{\sqrt {ax} {K_1}\left( {\sqrt {ax} } \right)\sqrt {bx} {K_1}\left( {\sqrt {bx} } \right)}}{{x+1}}dx}$ as non elementary function?

Tags: integration

Is it possible to rewrite this integral as any known non elementary function

$\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\sqrt {ax} {K_1}\left( {\sqrt {ax} } \right)\sqrt {bx} {K_1}\left( {\sqrt {bx} } \right)}}{{x + 1}}dx} $  where $a,b > 0$

Notice that ${K_1}\left( x \right)$ is the the modified Bessel function of the second kind ([here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselK.html))

With the help of Mathematica, I know that a  part of the original function can be rewritten with  $G$ as the MeijerG function that was documented by Mathematica at [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeijerG.html).

[image]

Comment: The first thing I would consider is making the change of variable $u=\sqrt{x}$ ! Then I would try to use one of the integral representations of $K_1$ as given [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32) or express the $K_1$s as functions involving the $J_n$s for which there are more results;

Comment: Could you make a comment ? This site is made for dialog... Besides, you have written at first that one should find $\zeta(3)$ and you have erased it ? Is it still true ?

Comment: An interesting paper (in a probability context) https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176995427 has made me think that it could be possible to apply preservation of dot product in Fourier Transform... or use Laplace Tranform.

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry but I do not post anything about this symbol  ζ(3) ?

Comment: Sorry, I have probably misread your first version (you modified it a short time after posting).